# Installing SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I have installed SQL Server with Microsoft Visual Studio and now I need to use SQL Server Management Studio and there is no such application in the Start menu. It just has Import and Export Data and SQL Server Configuration Manager. What do I do next?

---

when i tried to install the sql server 2008 from the given link by MrKow it gives the following error

### TITLE: SQL Server Setup failure.

SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:

Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created..

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

so now help what to do next ??

Answer (score 6):

It is a different download and not part of Visual Studio.

It is part of SQL Server and can be found on the install media (CD/DVD) - you can also download the express edition for free, [SSMS 2005 here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en) and [SSMS 2008 here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b).

Comment: and even i have installed management studio 2005 but when write the name of my server SQL server (SqlExpress) it does not connect it and this is te only running server other two's are not running so now what to do ??

Comment: @mAs - there is also a [2008 version](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b).

Answer (score 1):

By default, the SQL Server installation does not install the client tools, including SQL Server Management Studio.  You can relaunch the SQL Server installation and add the client tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Express edition of SSMS [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 1):

Put the SQL Server CD Rom in the drive and follow the step.
When you see the screen : "Feature selection"  under "Shared Features"  choose "Management Tools - Basic" and "Management Tools - Complete"

Leave the rest unchecked as you already installed the database.

Comment: i dont have any cd dvd of sql server i have installed it with visual studio 2010 so any alternate ?? i have dvd of visual studio 2010 and when i eun sql server installation center and when i select to add new features by selecting visual studio media dvd it doesnt load and run from it ??

Comment: Then you installed SQL Express. You can download the 2008 Version of Management studio on this link ( http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b )  or use the link in this answer ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188252/sql-managment-problem/4188272#4188272 ) for the 2005 version.

Comment: thanks buddy m downloading it and if i'll face any sort if problem i'll come back